# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

New to React Native:

I started a brand new project with Expo init and then I followed  the instructions mentioned inhttps://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

I run the project with expo start and I get this error.
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

```
invariant
    browser.js:38:14
runApplication
    AppRegistry.js:193:13
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:425:19
__guard$argument_0
    MessageQueue.js:112:6
__guard
    MessageQueue.js:373:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:111:4
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: We just had the same problem, still not quite sure what the actual problem is but deleting `.expo` `.expo-shared` `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and if you are using yarn then `yarn.lock`. And then running `npm run start` did the trick

Comment: This happened to me when removing and changing packages in package.json. Eg, I upgraded react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler, and then removed @react-native-community/masked-view etc. I reverted all changes and it's working again.

Comment: @oliverwebr I followed your instructions and now I get expo: command not found

Comment: Well sorry before you do a npm run start you need to install your node_modules again. So `npm i && npm run start` I meant actually. Best of luck to you @sean-h

Answer (score 53):

Open the `index.js`, the content of the file should be like this:

```js
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('X', () => App);

if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    const rootTag = document.getElementById('root') || document.getElementById('X');
    AppRegistry.runApplication('X', { rootTag });
}
```

If you have this error `Invariant Violation: “main” has not been registered` you have to replace the `'X'` by `'main'`.

Another example :

If you have this error `Invariant Violation: “app” has not been registered` you have to replace the `'X'` by `'app'`.

**For android :**

Open `./android/app/src/main/java/[multiple folders]/MainActivity.java`

```java
/**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
   * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "X";
  }
```

The `'X'` of `MainActivity.java` and `index.js` must match.

Comment: In my case, if statement was not necessary but changing the app name in specified folders did the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my case I change my app name in app.json and android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml but showing the "Invariant Violation: 'mypreviousappname' has not been registered"

So I change the name in MainActivity.java as your example and works. Thanks :)

Comment: For me, since I am using expo, I was not able to edit the index.js... are there any other solutions?

Comment: Making these mistakes and learning everyday. Thanks for this answer. BTW i got this error when i used ios directory from other project and used that in my current project (as that seems to be an easy way to update an older project instead of manually updating everything).

Comment: this is correct. In my case, I changed app.json "name" which was not the same as the project target

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

1. delete node_modules and your lockfile (package-lock.json / yarn.lock)
2. change the expo package version in package.json to 38.0.8
3. run yarn or npm install
4. run expo install react-native-safe-area-context

Comment: this worked for me, if you're things are looking weird then try doing the above

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that if you are using expo then you have to registerComponent differently. All the information is in the docs. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Answer (score 17):

**index.js**

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent("X", () => Root);
```

If you are facing this issue in `Android` then make sure that both `mainactivity.java` and `index.js` contains same "X"

**mainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
   return "X";
}
```

If you are facing this issue in `iOS` then make sure that both `AppDelegate.m` and `index.js` contains same "X"

**AppDelegate.m**

```
 RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"X" initialProperties:nil];
```

Comment: Only one that worked for me on iOS, thanks a lot

Comment: I created a copy of a app and just missed this to change .

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the problem was solved when I called

`AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName.toLowerCase(), () => App);`

in index.js.  So it looks like the first parameter is to be passed based on what error message is shown.  In my case, my project name was AwesomeProject and the error reported by Metro was:

`Invariant Violation: "awesomeproject" has not been registered.`

so I figured that adding toLowerCase() will solve the problem and it did!!

However, I was facing this problem when trying to run it on macos using `npx react-native run-macos` and after this was solved, I tried to invoke the iOS version, then I got `Invariant Violation: "AwesomeProject" has not been registered`.

So finally I got both working by registering the App twice as below:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName.toLowerCase(), () => App);
```

The same also works with `npx react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 10):

workarounded by:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
```

Comment: Wow what? This did it. Can you please explain more about why this works?

Comment: I don't know how but this actually worked.

Comment: In which file ?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was missing some packages which are mandatory to install.

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Comment: I had everything installed except react-native-community/masked-view as that wasnt specified when I installed navigation drawer (thats when I started getting the err) but after I installed react-native-community, now all issues are solved. thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `react-native-reanimated` and Expo, make sure to install it using:

`expo install react-native-reanimated`

[See the documentation for further help](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/)

Comment: This worked for me. But in 2023 the new install command is ```npx expo install react-native-reanimated```

Comment: `npx expo install react-native-reanimated` fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

Change your index.js .

```
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from "react-native";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
if (Platform.OS == "android") {
  registerRootComponent(App);
} else {
  AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and simple, thanks!

Comment: @SamilAbud Maybe you should try create the your app.json

Answer (score 4):

Your app name from './app.json' must be the same as in the getMainComponentName method on MainActivity.java.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

In my case it a specific package called `graphql-type-json` that was the problem.
So the 2nd part of the error was referring to the real issue:

- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called."'

The loading of the incriminated package was throwing an error 'GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".' which stopped the App loading and threw the Invariant Violation error.

After removing precisely the graphql-type-json (yarn remove graphql-type-json) package, expo loaded fine again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a class that existed solely to model the structure of a meal i.e not a react class component. I forgot to export that class but was calling it in the application 
 `new Meal(foo, bar .....)` 
  and that triggered this error. I found it by just tracing my steps to the most recent addition I had made before I started getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

import app name from **app.json** like this:

```
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
```

then add appname in registerComponent

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when "main" is not registered correctly in index.js.

You can use `registerRootComponent(App);` or `AppRegistry.registerComponent("main", () => App);` which do the same thing.

Most likely, the problem is not with your index.js file. You can test it by trying to build your app with an empty app an see if you get the same error.

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const testApp = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Test App</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

registerRootComponent(App);
```

If this works, **it most likely means another error happens before your app gets the change to be registered**. In my case, I was using a React library in a React Native project. Removing the import statement solved the issue. I suggest reintroducing each part of your app one at a time and seeing which part breaks it. Or revert to a previous commit when the issue wasn't there and see which library was added to the project.

Expo explains it well here: https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/application-has-not-been-registered/

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to get this error is that, for some reason, App.js is not functioning properly. It may be because that you are running the server from a wrong folder. In my case, I always got another error along with this error, so I kept fixing those and this error got resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the application and package name using `react-native-rename`,
in the file `ios/AppName/AppDelegate.mm`
Synchronize the application name with the app.json file by finding the line`UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"AppName", nil);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at diagnosing these stack traces but my project just suddenly started throwing this error. I installed `react-native-skeleton-content` which then threw errors for `react-native-gesture-handler` here I am thinking that gesture handler was just a result of some other peer dependency updating.

I uninstalled both and voila. The expo server runs again and processes the app just fine. Had I slept on it I never would have known but yeah, as a newbie, try deleting a new package you just installed and it's dependencies. It's likely the cause of a new issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, we need to make one additional change in `ios>appName>AppDelegate.mm` file,

Search for `RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView` and update *old_app_name* to *new_app_name*

Answer (score 0):

Deleting node modules and `package_lock.json` and npm or yarn install worked for me:

1. Delete these folders
2. Run npm install or yarn install

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this on my project by:

removing node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

then reinstalling:

```
npm install
```

then in **index.js** I replaced my import app with:

```
import { name as app } from "./app.json"
```

then in **index.js** I changed the code to:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(app, () => App)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `NavigationContainer` from @react-navigation/native and enclose all the code within `NavigationContainer` component. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this by adding ExpoModulesProvider.swift into Xcode Build Phase -> Compile Sources.

[image: add ExpoModulesProvider.swift to Xcode Compile Sources]

Answer (score 0):

I can fix that inssue with following changes in my projecct, im create a new file called index.ts(im  use typescript) and add in this file add:

```
import { AppRegistry, } from "react-native";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "./App";

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);
registerRootComponent(App);
```

besides change the "main" field in package.json by index file

```
{
  "name": "paondees-client-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.3.1",
    "expo": "^50.0.5",
    "expo-location": "~16.5.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-geolocation": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.10.0",
    "react-native-notifications": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

sorry for my english level

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was due to wrong name used at `getMainComponentName()` in `MainActivity.kt` in the android folder (as I was attempting the android device). Search the name it shows in Code editor (like in this case was `main` which is challenging to search) inside the ios/android directory and ensure it matched with what is being used in the `AppRegistery.registerComponent` name.

Answer (score -1):

It can happen after you've used `expo prebuild --clean` and when in your `Podfile`/`AppDelegate.m` was some 3rd party library specific import, like `react-native-maps`, or `Google Maps API Key`.

You'd need to put back these imports into `Podfile`/`AppDelegate.m`, next `cd ios`, next `pod install`. Still, `expo start` **might be not enough** and you'd need to build your project using `Xcode`. After building & running your code on `Xcode`, the error will be gone and the emulator will start.

There is some difference between how `Expo` and `Xcode` build/simulate the app, but I'm at quite an early stage regarding distinguishing these differences. I've also noticed sometimes you need to first build the project on `Xcode` first, if the app isn't installed on the `simulator` yet, and only then running the app from simulator launched via `expo start --dev-client`. Otherwise, I was getting an error

> Error: The development client (com.XYZ.ABC) for this project is not installed. Please build and install the client on the simulator first.`or`Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.`or`Invatian Violation: 'main' has not been registered...

Comment: I am using expo because I have windows and can't run Xcode

Comment: @Rolf, it looks like I could see the log for `iOS`, can't really help.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution that worked for me!

I just execute it again:

```bash
npm install -g expo-cli
```

ps.: In my case, it may have happened because I tried to install Turtle CLI and had to remove it to free disk space. This may have corrupted the expo files.

Answer (score -2):

The following worked for me:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
```

Comment: This exact answer already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137029/4883195), no need to post it again