# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeUnimoduleProxy.viewManagersNames.includes')

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded expo from sdk 44 to sdk 45 and I get those 2 errors that I can't solve.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeUnimoduleProxy.viewManagersNames.includes')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
 * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
 * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Any idea how can I fix it? The app is a managed expo project.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion can help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62649381/18667225

Comment: installing `expo install expo-modules-core` fixed the issue. https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules/issues/142#issuecomment-1141401312

Comment: Also dont forget to add "AppRegistry.registerComponent(() => Root);" in index.js file

Answer (score 6):

Here are the two steps I followed to resolve the issue in my case

```
 1. expo install expo-modules-core
 2. AppRegistry.registerComponent(() => Root); in index.js file
```

Comment: I am not sure where to put AppRegistry.registerComponent(() => Root); I do not have an index.js file and I would think the AppRegistry would need to be imported from somewhere? - but in my case just step 1 fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

here just what helped me after a lot of struggling :-D

if you are installing new sdk45 from older and have skeleton content in your react native app replace to this one:
-> https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content/issues/66

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).