# React native app works with expo go but not when transpiled to an APK

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, onesignal

I'm trying to create a simple project using expo.

Here is the code of my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';



const YourApp = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text>Try editing me! </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default YourApp;
```

When I run `npx expo start` and run the program in my phone by scanning the QR code. But when I transpile the program using `eas build -p android --profile preview` and install the program the app crashes (both in my android phone and in my android tablet.

Here is my `app.json`:

```
{
  {
  "expo": {
    "name": "v5",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "4fc3529c-f92f-43aa-bc19-8f72f43e14a5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "push-notification",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "metro-core": "^0.79.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and here is the bug:

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
```

I've searched the previous topics on this subject and haven't found a useful answer. Starting the project from scratch didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

I started a project from scratch and tried to call the app registry in main.

Comment: Note: I didn't understand the instructions of the following post, because I have an App.js main file instead of an index.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649381/invariant-violation-main-has-not-been-registered.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `main` key in `package.json` is set to `node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js`. Where does your `registerRootComponent` live?

Perhaps you could try to create an `index.js` file, and put the app registry line in there. It would look like:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import YourApp from './src/YourApp';

registerRootComponent(YourApp);
```

Then, try changing the path that `main` is looking at to the path where `index.js` is.