Importing from @stripe/stripe-react-native causes an error
I have a react native expo project. Following the docs : https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet
Importing ANYTHING from @stripe/stripe-react-native gives me the following error after a built:
`> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes `

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import MainStack from "./components/navigation/MainStack";
//import { initStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-react-native";  Error
const client = new QueryClient();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
        <MainStack />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
`

I've tried multiple cleanups and reccomendations (mostly from chatGPT) and nothing fixes it. Running it in a fresh expo project has no issues tho.

Anything here can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649381/invariant-violation-main-has-not-been-registered
